# VI(M), search in two files and scroll to result in two files automatically

Tags: vi, vim, vim-macros

I have been doing these operation and require to do it often.

> step 1. Search for a string (SHFT + *)
>   step 2. Switch to previous view port (CTRL + w + h)
>   step 3. Find the string ( n )
>   step 4. Return to the other view port (CTRL + w + l)

With Vi(m), is it possible to automate above 4 steps in one go?

I searched the net and stackoverflow, I am NOT talking about :set scrollbind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer and the clue by IngoKarkat about mapping lead to this
 `:nnoremap <F3> <S-*><C-w>hn<C-w>l`
 and this work like a charm.

Function key `F3` is key mapping.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to apply a `:substitute` to multiple buffers, you can use `:windo`, `:bufdo`, `:argdo`.

---

For searching, you can streamline the window switching with a mapping. For example, to move to the next match in the previous window (without staying in that window):

```
:nnoremap <C-w>n <C-w>pn<C-w>p
```

To make this support a `[count]`:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <C-w>n :<C-u>wincmd p<Bar>execute 'normal!' v:count1 . 'n'<Bar>wincmd p<CR>
```

Comment: I am learning to use vim, I read the help and understood very little, could you please explain, I did not succeed using the mapping yet...

Comment: You put that mapping into your `~/.vimrc`, or type it into Vim (to try it out). It's triggered by first pressing `Ctrl+W`, followed by `n`.